# How to get child model having foregin key of parent model in Django rest framwork?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

now i want output such a way that there for each list i must get entire timing record how to achieve it
below is my model

```
model.py
class Refreshment(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
     charges = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, help_text="Charges per hour")





class Timeing(models.Model):
    refreshment = models.OneToOneField(Refreshment,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     sunday_open = models.TimeField(blank=True, editable=True)
```

Below is my views.py

```
@api_view()
def all_games_sports(request):
  entertainment = Refreshment.objects.filter(type=1)
  serialize = EntertainmentSerializer(instance=entertainment, many=True)
  main = {'status': True, 'code': "CODE_SUCCESSFUL", 'msg': "SUCCESS", 'all_games_sports': serialize.data}
  return Response(main)
```

Serializer.py

```
class TimeingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
      model = Timeing
      fields = '__all__'

class EntertainmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      refreshment =   TimeingSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)

  class Meta:
      model = Refreshment
      fields = '__all__'

AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for    field `refreshment` on serializer `AvailableHourSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Refreshment` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Refreshment' object has no attribute 'refreshment'.
```

Comment: You should take care of that in your `EntertainmentSerializer`. Also post the code for `EntertainmentSerializer`

Comment: edited please review

Comment: what is the result of your current code, and what do you want it to be?

Answer (score 1):

Your code throws an error. It should. You defined `refreshment`, but not added it to fields.

```
class EntertainmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      refreshment =  TimeingSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)

      class Meta:
          model = Refreshment
          fields = '__all__' #You have not added refreshment to fields.
```

You should be doing this instead:

```
class EntertainmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      timeing =   TimeingSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)

      class Meta:
          model = Refreshment
          fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: got error. how updated error at to bottom of question